# I can't find a MongoDB Database on my data/db path

Tags: mongodb

I created a test database using `use testdb` on my Mongo directory, after that i went to my `data\db` path but i did not find any file named `testdb` there. Is my database stored in some other way or is it just somewhere else?

Before creating the db, i set my path with `--dbpath C:\mongodb\data\db`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specified DB path stored the data created by running mongod process. If you've not specified `directoryPerDB`, it will store data for all databases into the same directory specified in dbpath.

MongoDB creates a file for each index and each collection in a dbpath which is normally not identifiable by its name. You can not locate a directory name for your DB's.